# Error: Cannot find module 'jade' (after switching to pug)

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I am trying to go through the tutorial:

https://closebrace.com/tutorials/2017-03-02/the-dead-simple-step-by-step-guide-for-front-end-developers-to-getting-up-and-running-with-nodejs-express-and-mongodb

But I want to use latest `pug` to avoid deprecation warnings. After doing `npm start` and accessing `localhost:3000` I am getting the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'jade'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:542:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:472:25)
at Module.require (module.js:585:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at new View (/home/nikita/project/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:79:30)
at Function.render (/home/nikita/project/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:570:12)
at ServerResponse.render (/home/nikita/project/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:971:7)
at /home/nikita/project/app.js:43:7
at Layer.handle_error (/home/nikita/project/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:71:5)
at trim_prefix (/home/nikita/project/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:315:13)
```

`package.json` and `package-lock.json` have `pug` there, no `jade`.

I tried to substitute `jade` for `pug` in `app.js`:

> app.set('view engine', 'jade') -->  app.set('view engine', 'pug')

But it can not run still giving an error:

> Error: Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory

Comment: You just have to change your `view engine` from `jade` to `pug`. I.e. `app.set('view engine', 'pug')`

Comment: already did, not working

Comment: What do you have on the line 43 in `app.js` file?

Comment: res.render('error');

Comment: OK, in `views` directory files are of `jade` type. Should I change them to `pug`?

Comment: Yes, change it to `.pug` format

Comment: OK, working fine. Thank you!